# apollo client give error 500 while creating a page

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, graphql-js

I’m creating headless CMS website using WordPress, nextjs and graphql. I added apollo-client in news page to create pagination with a
load-more button, but it gives me the following error **“ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 500”** I’m a beginner in using nextjs and apollo graphql and would appreciate the help, thank you.

here’s the apollo client code I’m using:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
const defaultOptions = {
    watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
        errorPolicy: "ignore",
    },
    query: {
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
        errorPolicy: "all",
    },
};
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    resultCaching: false,
});
const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_NEXT_URL}/graphql`,
})
console.log(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_NEXT_URL}/graphql`, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_NEXT_URL)
const client = new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: true,
    link,
    cache,
    defaultOptions,
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
});

export default client;
```

and the news page it's in directory pages/news/index.js

```
const News = ( { data } ) => {
  return (
    <Layout data={data}>
      <LoadMorePosts posts={data?.posts}/>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default News;
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data, errors } = await client.query( {
    query: GET_NEWS,
    variables: {
      uri: '/news/',
      first: PER_PAGE_FIRST,
      after: null,
    },
  } );
  const defaultProps = {
    props: {
      data: data || {}
    },
    revalidate: 1,
    credentials: 'include',

  };
  return handleRedirectsAndReturnData( defaultProps, data, errors, 'posts' );
}
```

**Server Error log**

```
Server Error
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
new ApolloError
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/errors.cjs.js (31:28)
<unknown>
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js (1493:19)
both
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (963:53)
<unknown>
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (956:72)
new Promise
<anonymous>
Object.then
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (956:24)
Object.error
file:///node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (964:49)
notifySubscription
file://node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify
file://node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:3)
SubscriptionObserver.error
file://node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:7)
<unknown>
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (946:68)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
iterateObserversSafely
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (946:25)
Object.error
file://node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js (1039:21)
notifySubscription
file:/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify
file:/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:3)
```